# How do I make a specific cell change based on what another cell says

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I’m trying to make a ***spot the difference*** type activity, and if you type the correct different ID (F11) into a certain place (L7) then L10 will display a certain Text.

Something like

If L7 says `"F11"` then L7 should say `Good Job!`

How would I do that?

```
=IF (L7="F11") L10= "Good Job!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just need a bit different syntax:

```
=IF(L7 = "F11","Good Job!","Not very good job?")
```

Here's a reference to Google Docs help center:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Use `IFS()` function.

```
=IFS(L7="F11","Good Job")
```

[image]